# How to append table with the firebase data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase example:

Users:

- User1

  - A

    - abc
    - def
    - ghi
  - B

    - abc
    - def
    - ghi
  - C

    - abc
    - def
    - ghi

I wanted to display "abc", "def", "ghi" value. However my code only displays "abc". Below are my code.

```
<html>
<body onload="initialize()">

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/5.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/5.5.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script src="test.js" ></script>
<div class="Medbox">


        <p>Search User
        <input type="text"  id="User_Field" placeholder="Enter User">
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchValue()">
        </p>

        <p>Current Values: </p>
        <table id="abcTable" class="abcTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <td><b>InfoA</b></td>
            <td><b>InfoB</b></td>
            <td><b>InfoC</b></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="TableBody">
        </tbody>    
        </table>

</div>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
function initialize(){
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyB6eYZBKDsasdasddsamjxj2t2k4TI",
authDomain: "medimate-ead90.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://asdasd.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "asdas",
storageBucket: "mdasdasd.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "5256151964"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
database = firebase.database();
}

function SearchValue(){

var searchedUser = User_Field.value;
var ref = firebase.database().ref("User/" +searchedUser);
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
var childData = childSnapshot.val();

let el = document.querySelector("#TableBody");
el.innerHTML = childKey;
document.appendChild(el);
 });
});
}
```

I wanted the code to read if "B" or "C" exist, they will make another row to display the "abc","def","ghi" values as well. I am a student and new to firebase, please help or advice. Thank you